# Method returning a non-null value still assigns null to a variable

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have a method that searches something in my database according to a field. when calling that method and saving the returning value in a variable, the returning value is not null at the end of the function. After the function has been called and I debug what is available in my variable, the value is still null!

In one class I have:

```cs
var box = _someClass.GetBoxByRfidAsync("testvalue");
```

```cs
public Box GetBoxByRfidAsync(string rfid)
{
    var foundBox = _dc.Boxes
        .Include(b => b.Stack)
        .Include(b => b.Type)
        .Where(box => box.RFID1 == rfid)
        .FirstOrDefault();

     return foundBox;
}
```

The box class looks like this:

```cs
public class Box
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RFID1 { get; set; }
    public string Rit { get; set; }
    public Stack Stack { get; set; }
    public int PosInStack { get; set; } //lowest box is 0, highest is 7
    public BoxType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Inserted { get; set; }

}
```

The method gets executed and at the end of GetBoxByRfidAsync I can see using the debugger that foundBox is NOT null.

I step over the end of the function and go to the assignment of the foundBox value to the box variable. For some reason the 'box' variable stays null and does not change.

The box variable should be equal to the foundBox value, but it stays null.

Here are some screenshots of my debugging session:

[image: End of method]
[image: Immediate window showing box is still null]

Comment: Just to be sure: is it possible that you just need to hit F10 another time? If `foundBox` is not null, it will surely be assigned to `box`. When you step through with F10 and leave the method, the assignment did just not yet happen.

Comment: to be clear: if you add, before `return foundBox` the line `if (foundBox == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("foundBox is null");`, **and** you add, after the `var box = ...` the line `if (box == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("box is null");` - do you get the second exception?

Comment: Can you post the code for the method that throws? Is it `GetStackWithLocationAndCoordinates` ? Also the box class.

Comment: @AvinKavish speculation, but I wonder if `Box` implements `IEnumerable<Foo>` for some `Foo`, and the IDE is trying to evaluate the iterator to display the contents. but the implementation of `GetEnumerator()` in the type is touching a field that is `null` in this scenario

Comment: @AvinKavish The error gets thrown on line 292 where I ask for the box.Type, that gives me the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you show in the debugger doesn't mean that `box` is `null`. If `box` was `null`, it would literally just report: `null`.

Instead, the `box` is non-`null`, and something that the debugger is evaluating **to display the value** is throwing an exception. Perhaps a broken `ToString()`. The fact that it mentions `ListDictionaryInternal` means that you might want to look *in particular* at any collection or dictionary usage inside the type, and perhaps anything that is marked with "debugger" attributes such as `[DebuggerDisplay(...)]`.

If you want to test whether `box` is `null`, ask the immediate console:

`box == null`

and it will return `true` or `false` (caveat: assuming that there isn't a broken static equality operator, which is also possible; to avoid that, a good alternative is:

`box is object`

which will reliably return `true` if it is non-`null`, and `false` if it is `null`, without using static equality operators.

---

Edit: based on the discussion in the comments, I'm overwhelmingly convinced that this is a broken `==` operator, as demonstrated here:

[image]

Comment: Both of those statements return the same error of the NullReferenceException. When hovering over the box variable during debugging, nothing appears either, any idea what could cause that? Otherwise I will probably rewrite that part of the application.

Comment: @Bastienverschaete if those statements return a `NullReferenceException`, then I'm even more suspicious about a broken static `==` operator. Please check the operators. The **only** way that `foo == null` can throw an exception is : via a broken static `==` operator

Comment: Before you rewrite anything give us a stack trace and the code for the method that throws. So far you have only presented speculation and a theory on nulls, no hard evidence. Where do you observe that box is null and how do you know that it is causing the exception that you describe?

Comment: @Bastienverschaete I've added an image to show **exactly** how a broken `==` operator can cause exactly this scenario on a non-`null` value (although I guess that once an `==` operator is involved, it could also throw for a `null` value)

Comment: @AvinKavish you're asking for something that clearly isn't available; the OP is showing us what they're doing - testing something for `null` in the immediate window. They have correctly shown what is available. The IDE doesn't tell us "by the way, I'm calling your custom `==` operator here" (which is what I suspect is happening)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the explanation, atleast I now know that the value can't possibly be null. I did not change the operators so I wouldn't see how they could be broken, but you've given me a path to work with, I will look into it a bit more and will mark the question as resolved.

Comment: I'm not asking for something that isn't available, I'm asking for a stack trace of the exception. What does your screenshot about a `System.InvalidOperationExeption` have to do with a null reference exception? This anwser is irrelavant and presented without knowing all the facts.

Comment: @Bastienverschaete another edge possibility: can you look at what `box?.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` is? I wonder whether what you're actually seeing here is EF returning a *proxy* that isn't actually a `Box`, but rather is a `SomeOtherType : Box`, and the bug is in the code that *you can't see* (because it is in the proxy).

Comment: @AvinKavish the point I was trying to make is: the issue *as asked in the question* is based on a false premise - specifically (quoting) "For some reason the 'box' variable stays null and does not change." and "The box variable should be equal to the foundBox value, but it stays null.". This is important, because that is an *incorrect assumption*, which is what I have been trying to highlight. There are a few ways in which a non-null value can cause the kind of error reported in the question (and in particular their screenshot), which is what I have been trying to illustrate.

Comment: @AvinKavish as for the `InvalidOperationException` - that was merely an arbitrary example to illustrate

Comment: @Bastienverschaete actually, we may already have that - I think `Box <>m0` is your dynamic proxy; so in particular, I wonder whether EF is generating a dynamic proxy that is broken, and which (crucially) also has one of: a broken ToString, a broken DebuggerDisplay, or a broken custom `==` (or perhaps a few other ways of getting the IDE's `box == null` to fail)

Comment: Well you should outright tell OP that his assumptions are incorrect because C# works fine, that's what I'm trying to figure out too, if OP shows the stack trace I'm willing to bet that it's thrown from one of the internal layers of EF Core wiring, which we can't say without the full stack trace. We all know that methods return values fine, if method's didn't return values that would be disastrous. (But in his post he is trying to say the method doesn't return the value properly !!!)

Comment: "We all know that methods return values fine" - you'd be amazed at some of the compiler and JIT bugs I've filed... even that isn't always true

Comment: Oh that's interesting

Comment: @MarcGravell I eventually fixed my issue but I have no idea why or how it works, but simply changing my variable name from 'box' to anything else solved it. That variable was not used in the rest of my method or class so I have no idea why this gave me issues, but my code works perfectly now. Thank for looking into this with me though!

Comment: @Bastienverschaete that is ... incredibly odd. I'd love to see a repro of that, but I imagine it would be hard to show in an isolated example :(